On demand water heater causing electrical issues
I have an EcoSmart ECO 11 Tankless Water heater that is causing various electrical issues when running.  Here are some of those issues:

Loud buzzing sound from the main breaker panel.  The is NOT coming from the 60 Amp breaker tied to the circuit but the main 200 Amp breaker.  There is no feel of vibration in the 60 Amp or the 200 Amp, it is simply an audible buzzing.
Dimmable smart switch causing dimmable LED lights to dim.  This dimming is not just at the start up of the water heater.  They dim and stay dim as long as the heater is running.
Humming from ceiling fan.  When the heater is on, we get a rhythmic hum from our ceiling fan.
Faint buzz from outlets.  I don't hear it, but my wife says that she can hear a faint buzz coming from the outlets just like we hear in the main breaker panel.

So far, this is what we've done to mitigate the issue.

Power company has come out and confirmed all lines are tight and there is no issue from the meter to the pole.  Initial suspicion was a lose neutral.
All lugs and screws tight in main panel.  We had a local electrical company come out and verify that all connections were tight inside the panel.  Main lugs as well as all hots and neutrals.
All connections are tight at the disconnect and inside the water heater.
Measured the resistance on the two heating elements inside the water heater against a new elements and both checked out fine.
Contacted the vendor (EcoSmart) and they indicated that there is nothing within their heater that can cause this issue (I respectfully disagreed).  I escalated my inquiry to a supervisor and he suggested replacing the control board.  I did and it did not fix the issue.
I turned off the breaker for the water heater and loaded up every circuit I could to apply a large load on the main breaker.  The water heater drew about 42 Amps when running.  I was able to load up the main breaker to almost 75 Amps with no buzzing or other adverse effects.
I spoke to every Electrician and Electrical Engineer I could and nobody can explain to me what is going on or how to fix it.

I do not want to simple replace the water heater, which would be a huge pain, unless I can determine what is causing the issue.  I welcome any and all suggestions.
I did find another thread on this forum but it did not really provide a solution.
Tankless Electric water heater Electrical interference

How old is the main breaker and what panel is it in?  Possible the main breaker with the 48 amps plus the house amps is having problems inside.  Breakers are usually dependable for many years, but there are always the odd one that is defective or fails when you go to turn it on again.  An electrician was doing some work, ask me to turn the main back on.  Was nice the electrician stayed and pulled the meter and changed the breaker.

Dim lights are a concerning symptom.  You need to check hot-to-neutral voltage on both legs.  Also check neutral to ground voltage on any subpanel if you have one.

It may not be your wiring. Your utilities company may need to determine if your localized power grid isn't having brown-out conditions.   Too much load in the neighborhood, versus just your house.  Ask your neighbors if they've had dim lights from freezer/fridge/AC powering on.

@crip659
The main breaker is only about 5 years old.  The sound does not appear to be related to the load.  If I just use the water heater (42 amps) I get the noise and other affects.  If I turn off the water heater and load up the main with other circuits ( over 70 Amps) I get no noise or other affects.  Not sure if a bad main breaker would cause all the issues I'm having.

@Robert
The electrician checked all not to neutral voltages and found no issues.  The LED lights only dim on circuits connected a smart switch (Alexa).  LED lights that are not on a smart dimming switch do not dim when the hot water heater comes on.

@Bee
No issues with our neighbors.  The power company installed a monitoring device on my meter for several days and found no problems.  They did indicate I had over 700 Amps available to my house.

Did the electrician hear the buzzing?  Buzzing breakers are usually not normal.  Can also see this question that is a bit similar.   https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/241708/hot-water-heater-causing-buzzing-grinding-sound-in-circuit-breaker-panel?rq=1

@crip659, Yes, the electrician did hear the buzzing and was unable to determine the cause.  It was likely the main breaker but since we were not able to feel any vibration could not determine conclusively it was the main.  The only thing we didn't replace was the main breaker but I did open and close it several times to ensure it was functioning.
I'll take a look at the other post and see if there is anything I can do.

An old trick to pinpoint sound location is to use a wood dowel(or similar) against your ear.  Usually used on car engines.  I would prefer having a electrician who knows the safety precautions of working with live power do it.
